# Do I need a shared view for navigation between controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC and this is probably a really obvious thing...Basically, I can't access the "Forum" view which I had created inside "Home" folder (because I need a link to Forum on my main homepage.). I was wondering if it's okay to just move the Forum view into the Shared folder?
Is this somehow very bad practice? It seems like I have strong coupling now, because on the one hand the forum view gets called inside HomeController, and on the other hand it will pretty much always
be used with ForumController from now on. So that might be unnecessary/wrong somehow?

edit: If I do this, the URLs change in a weird way, there must be a better solution right? 
First when I click on forum link on main page, I'm at: /Home/Forum. I look at the forum, everything is fine.
Now I click on "Post a topic", and after the roundtrip I'm at /Forum/PostTopic. Home is gone.

Comment: What do you mean by a "link to Forum on my main page?"

Comment: @tvanfosson I mean this: http://imgur.com/50boo.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `ForumController` its associated views need to be located at `~/Views/Forum`.

For example:

```
public class ForumController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and then you would have the corresponding view in `~/Views/Forum/Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Forum";
}

<h2>Forum</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.
</p>
```

and finally you generate a link to the `Index` action of the `ForumController` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go to forum", "Index", "Forum")
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much more sense.